# Flutter Web: Sporadic Networking problem – how to troubleshoot?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, networking

I have a Flutter Web application running on Firebase hosting and using Cloud Firestore. Some of the users are having a problem with a Form that seems to hang and will not Save from time to time. This doesn’t happen all the time but maybe once a day or once a week. The users are on Windows 10 Pro with Edge as the only approved browser.
The temporary solution is to close that browser and start a new fresh browser. The Web App credentials are set to store locally, and login is automatic. Then things seem to work fine from there.
The screenshot of the error is below and it seems to indicate a Networking (FireStore (9.9.0) Connection WebChannel transport) error. The errors then seem to cascade from there.

I thought the issue might be that the Firebase_Auth token had expired but I tested opening the App on a browser on a local PC and then, after logging into the Web App I put the PC to Sleep, came back 8 hours later and everything worked fine. So, most likely not a problem with the Firebase_Auth token expiring.

So my question is, how do you log and troubleshoot a potential Networking communication error that doesn’t happen very often (the app runs fine most of the time)?
Below is the Flutter Doctor output, the Error as well as the relevant code.

> 

Flutter doctor shows:

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.4, on macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-arm,
> locale en-US)
>
> • Flutter version 3.3.4 on channel stable at
> /Users/XXX/Development/flutter
>
> • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
>
> • Framework revision eb6d86ee27 (5 months ago), 2022-10-04 22:31:45
> -0700
>
> • Engine revision c08d7d5efc
>
> • Dart version 2.18.2
>
> • DevTools version 2.15.0
>
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 31.0.0)
>
> • Android SDK at /Users/XXX/Library/Android/sdk
>
> • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
>
> • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
> Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
>
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
> 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)
>
> • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2) • Xcode at
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer • Build 14C18 • CocoaPods
> version 1.11.3
>
> [✓] Chrome - develop for the web • Chrome at /Applications/Google
> Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
>
> [✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
>
> • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
>
> • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
>
> https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
>
> • Dart plugin can be installed from:
>
> https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
>
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
> 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)
>
> [✓] Connected device (2 available) • macOS (desktop) • macos •
> darwin-arm64 • macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-arm • Chrome (web) • chrome •
> web-javascript • Google Chrome 110.0.5481.100
>
> [✓] HTTP Host Availability • All required HTTP hosts are available
>
> • No issues found!

The relevant code for the when the user Saves the entry is below:

```
 onPressed: () async {
                      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        setState(() {
                          _submitBtnText = 'Saving';
                        });
                        try {
                          Future.delayed(
                            const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                          );

                          /// TODO: move to separate Util call?
                          final schedulerEventMap = SchedulerEvent(
                                  title: '${_firstNameFormFieldController.text} ${_lastNameFormFieldController.text}',
                                  cemeteryLocation: targetEvent.cemeteryLocation,
                                  fname: _firstNameFormFieldController.text,
                                  lname: _lastNameFormFieldController.text,
                                  from: targetEvent.from,
                                  to: targetEvent.to,
                                  isCremated: targetEvent.isCremated,
                                  isVeteran: targetEvent.isVeteran,
                                  veteranBranch: targetEvent.veteranBranch,
                                  famServDir: _famServicesFormFieldController.text,
                                  funeralHome: targetEvent.showFuneralHomeList ? targetEvent.funeralHome : _funeralHomeFormFieldController.text,
                                  showFuneralHomeList: targetEvent.showFuneralHomeList,
                                  parish: targetEvent.showParishList ? targetEvent.parish : _parishFormFieldController.text,
                                  showParishList: targetEvent.showParishList,
                                  funeralServiceDateTime: targetEvent.funeralServiceDateTime,
                                  hasReception: targetEvent.hasReception,
                                  hasEscort: targetEvent.hasEscort,
                                  burialLocation: _burialLocationFormFieldController.text,
                                  showCommittalList: targetEvent.showCommittalList,
                                  placeOfCommittal: targetEvent.showCommittalList ? targetEvent.placeOfCommittal : _committalFormFieldController.text,
                                  showObcList: targetEvent.showObcList,
                                  outerBurialContainer: targetEvent.showObcList ? targetEvent.outerBurialContainer : _obcFormFieldController.text,
                                  obcOrderedBy: _obcOrderedByFormFieldController.text,
                                  obcOrderedDt: targetEvent.obcOrderedDt,
                                  hasWitness: targetEvent.hasWitness,
                                  removeMemorial: targetEvent.removeMemorial,
                                  flaggedBy1st: _flaggedBy1stFormFieldController.text,
                                  flaggedBy2nd: _flaggedBy2ndFormFieldController.text,
                                  blindCheckBy: _blindCheckByFormFieldController.text,
                                  groundStaffPrepSite: _groundStaffSitePrepFormFieldController.text,
                                  groundStaffCommittal: _groundStaffCommittalFormFieldController.text,
                                  cemeteryRepAtCommittal: _cemeteryRepCommittalFormFieldController.text,
                                  isPending: _isPending,
                                  createdDate: DateTime.now(),
                                  createdBy: '${_currentUser.fname} ${_currentUser.lname}',
                                  background: SchedulerUtils.setBackgroundColorForFirestore(targetEvent.cemeteryLocation!),
                                  isAllDay: false,
                                  eventType: kQptEventTypeFuneral)
                              .toFireStore();

                          /// if we have notes, then add then to the event
                          if (_notesFormFieldController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                            schedulerEventMap['notes'] = FieldValue.arrayUnion([
                              {
                                "date": DateTime.now(),
                                "notes": _notesFormFieldController.text,
                                "user": _currentUser,
                              },
                            ]);
                          }

                          /// now the we've got the complete event with notes, add it to FireStore
                          await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(kQptFireStoreEventCollection).add(schedulerEventMap);
                          formSubmit("Submitted without issues!");
                        } on Exception catch (e) {
                          formSubmit("Error submitting your event! 
${e.toString()}");                   
                        }
```

The errors that the user is seeing in the developer console are attached as images.[image: Connection Web Channel Transport]

Answer (score 0):

To get un-obfuscated reports of errors and exceptions happening in production environment for your Flutter app, you might want to use a service like Sentry (https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/flutter/) and its integrated Flutter package https://pub.dev/packages/sentry_flutter.

It will require you to either:

- Install Sentry on you own servers for free

  - (https://develop.sentry.dev/self-hosted/, might get painful If you want to add Github SSO integrations and such, but could be worth)
- ... or just use their own PaaS service (https://sentry.io/signup/)

Alongside with it, with each release you push to your users, you will need to ship to Sentry informations about your release, including debug symbols files (which are the sourcemaps that your `flutter build web --release --pub --build-number ${{ env.APP_BUILD_NUMBER }} --source-maps` will produce). If you are using GitHub Actions for you CI / CD pipeline, there is already an action for that : https://github.com/marketplace/actions/sentry-release

Good luck !